# Getting FileNotFoundException when trying to upload File to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: java, android, http, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to upload an image from Android to Cloud Storage. I'm following [this official guide](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/simple-upload) on how to upload files to Google Cloud Storage using the JSON API. Here is my code

```
private class uploadImage extends AsyncTask<File, Void, String> {

    File file = mPhotoFile;

    private String delimiter = "--";

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), mPhotoFile.getPath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(File... params) {


        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/backend-images/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject?key=my_key");
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            urlConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(mPhotoFile.getPath().getBytes().length));
            urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "my_key");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


            OutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
            InputStream responseStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader responseStreamReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responseStream));

            out.write(("Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n").getBytes());
            out.write(("Content-Length: " + String.valueOf(mPhotoFile.getPath().getBytes().length)).getBytes());
            out.write("\r\n".getBytes());
            out.write(mPhotoFile.getPath().getBytes());
            out.write("\r\n".getBytes());

            String line = "";
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            while((line = responseStreamReader.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            String response = stringBuilder.toString();

            Log.i("CloudStorage", response);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return e.getMessage();
        }

        return "Everything was a success";
    }


}
```

I'm using the Public API access method and appending the Api key to the link like  [the guide says I could](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/how-tos/authorizing#installed-applications) to authorize requests

Here is the error i'm getting

```
05-22 10:24:01.798 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:    java.io.FileNotFoundException:https://www.googleapis.com/upload/storage/v1/b/backend-images/o?uploadType=media&name=myObject?key=my_key
05-22 10:24:01.798 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err: at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:197)
05-22 10:24:01.798 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
05-22 10:24:01.798 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
05-22 10:24:01.798 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at com.example.kid.uimockup.HomeFragment$uploadImage.doInBackground(HomeFragment.java:636)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at com.example.kid.uimockup.HomeFragment$uploadImage.doInBackground(HomeFragment.java:605)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
05-22 10:24:01.803 3747-4045/com.example.kid.uimockup W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I don't have a clue if this is a problem on the client side or the server side

Comment: `?key=my_key` in your real code is this assigned a correct value or it's the same as this ?

Comment: I edited it, I have the real key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it work after making a few changes. I was getting a 401 Unauthorized Error code which means I didn't have authorization to access the bucket.

So instead of appending the query parameter `key=api_key`, i appended `access_token=auth_token` to authorize requests.

I then added `allUsers` permission to my bucket (making it public for everyone to write and read) and it worked.